# How do I figure out what AWS RDS instance does my Django application need?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I was wondering what AWS RDS instance does my Django application need. How does one figure that out? What kind of benchmarks should my Django application have to be suited for T3 or M5?

In the essence of the question, I want to find out how to figure out what kind of instance would be suited for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of RDS is that you can **start small and then up-size** any time by either scaling vertically and horizontal:

- [Scaling Your Amazon RDS Instance Vertically and Horizontally](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/)

Subsequently, you can **start with small** db instance type, and when you decide that it is too small, you can upgrade it to larger type. A decision on when to upgrade is commonly done based on **RDS metrics**:

- [Using Metrics to Identify Performance Issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html#CHAP_BestPractices.UsingMetrics)
- [Making better decisions about Amazon RDS with Amazon CloudWatch metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/making-better-decisions-about-amazon-rds-with-amazon-cloudwatch-metrics/)

The alternative is to use [Aurora Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.use-cases). The reason is that one of its use-cases is:

> You are deploying a new application and are **unsure about which instance size** you need. With Aurora Serverless , you can create a database endpoint and have the **database autoscale** to the capacity requirements of your application.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm deciding to settle with Heroku for testing the project out, giving it to a few people, moving to Digital Ocean as the traffic rises but isn't that much since I noticed that Digital Ocean is actually cheaper for projects that are just starting out and from there, I'll scale from AWS T3.small/medium to further up depending upon my use case.

Comment: @ArthTyagi No problem. Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your project. You can start with the basic free-tier db t2-micro and later scale up if needed. Generally you will be contacted by the customer support asking about the necessities. According to the [source](https://www.apptio.com/blog/choosing-the-right-rds-instance-for-the-job/), the databases and its uses:

```
T2: for workloads that require burstable performance capacity 
M4: for general-purpose database workloads
R3: for memory-intensive workloads, like in-memory functions, big data analysis, etc.
```